# Angular 8/9 - (Subscribing dynamically): How to automatically forkJoin while getting Observables from a collection?

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, rxjs6, fork-join

**First Step:**

Imagine, there is an object named `RouteObservables` somewhere in the project which I want to use (import) in many components:

```js
export const RouteObservables = {
  state$: 'this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(() => window.history.state))',
  url$: 'this.route.url',
  params$: 'this.route.params',
  queryParams$: 'this.route.queryParams',
  fragment$: 'this.route.fragment',
  data$: ' this.route.data'
};
```

**Second Step:**

I want to get to the following situation (by using the RouteObservables object above):

```js
 const state$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(() => window.history.state));
 const url$ = this.route.url;
 const params$ = this.route.params;
 const queryParams$ = this.route.queryParams;
 const fragment$ = this.route.fragment;
 const data$ = this.route.data;
```

**Third Step**

I want to use the same collection `RouteObservables` to start an `forkJoin` automatically:

```js
forkJoin([...Object.keys(RouteObservables)]).subscribe(
  (routeData: any) => {
    this.routeData = routeData;
  }
);
```

**Why do I need the `RouteObservables` object?**

I need the ordered sequence to access the correct data (e.g., `routeData[0]` will be my state object potentially transferred from the previous route). This object helps me not to miss some subscriptions to unsubscribe at the end (`ngOnDestroy`) too.

**My Question(s):**

- What is the most efficient way, to declare Observables in a sequence (I am interested in) in an object (or in a collection) so that I do some operations dynamically?
- If there is no proven (state of the art) way, how can I get from step first to step two?
- Can I spare the second step at all and get more elegantly to the third step?

**Edit1:**

Btw: `forkJoin` does not work with route (ActivatedRoute) observables in this way, because route observables do not complete. Following approach works but my questions are still existing:

```js
// excerpt!
// routeData is a public property 

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllRouteData();
}

getAllRouteData() {
  const state$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(() => window.history.state));

  const url$ = this.route.url;
  const params$ = this.route.params;
  const queryParams$ = this.route.queryParams;
  const fragment$ = this.route.fragment;
  const data$ = this.route.data;

  forkJoin(
    state$.pipe(first()),
    url$.pipe(first()),
    params$.pipe(first()),
    queryParams$.pipe(first()),
    fragment$.pipe(first()),
    data$.pipe(first())
  ).subscribe(
    (routeData: any) => {
      this.routeData = routeData;
      this.start();
    },
    (error: any) => {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    }
  );
}
```

**Edit2: Current Workaround** (`routeObservables` is not really reusable in other components)

```js
 getAllRouteData() {
    const routeObservables = [
      this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(() => window.history.state)),
      this.route.url,
      this.route.params,
      this.route.queryParams,
      this.route.fragment,
      this.route.data
    ];

    forkJoin(routeObservables.map(r => r.pipe(first()))).subscribe(
      (routeData: any) => {
        this.routeData = routeData;
      }
    );
  }
```

**Why do I ask?**

My biggest problem is "single responsibility", I am trying to avoid copy+paste-code (e.g. `routeObservables` above in each component, that needs route related data).

Comment: @dev I've added more information. The object is placed in a central location in the project  (within a ts.-file) so that many people can import and use it. I would like to do it dynamically, i.e. without making every single assignment manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main problem is that you have string values and need to use them as Javascript objects, right? In that case, you can use access these properties with square brackets:

```
const keys = Object.keys(this.RouteObservables);
const sources = this.keys.map(key => this[this.RouteObservables.key]);

forkJoin(...this.sources).subscribe(
  (routeData: any) => {
    this.routeData = routeData;
  }
);
```

p.s. class must have `this.route` injected in its constructor.

Haven't tested, but I think this should do the trick. Give me know if any errors.

Comment: one problem: route observables do not like `forkJoin`, I guess. (in combination with `state$` no data is available.

Comment: Yes, `forkJoin` will not emit anything if any of its Observables does not complete (and these `router` Observables doe not complete). You can try `concat`, it also emits in order

Comment: `concat` works but it returns a `BehaviorSubject` not an object, I'm somehow confused,..

Comment: sorry, converting from string to "observable" does also not so work in this way

Comment: About string to Observable, remove `this` from strings otherwise you later get `this[this.route.url]`. So instead of `url$: 'this.route.url',` , use `url$: 'route.url',`. Same for others. And  for `concat` returns BehaviourSubject. Can you demonstrate that? Any errors?